# get the SUM between two given dates

Tags: mysql

if i want to get the total_consumption over a range of dates, how would i do that?

I thought i could do:

```
SELECT id, SUM(consumption) 
FROM consumption_info 
WHERE date_time BETWEEN 2013-09-15 AND 2013-09-16 
GROUP BY id;
```

however this returns: Empty set, 2 warnings(0.00 sec)

```
---------------------------------------
id | consumption |  date_time          |        
=======================================|
1  |      5      | 2013-09-15 21:35:03 |
2  |      5      | 2013-09-15 24:35:03 |
3  |      7      | 2013-09-16 11:25:23 |
4  |      3      | 2013-09-16 20:15:23 |
----------------------------------------
```

any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

thanks in advance

Comment: You asked this well and clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the date strings: the WHERE clause should actually be written as...

```
BETWEEN '2013-09-15' AND '2013-09-16'
```

The irony is that `2013-09-15` *is* a valid SQL expression - it means `2013 minus 09 minus 15`. Obviously, there's no date lying in between the corresponding results; hence an empty set in return

Yet there might be another, more subtle error here: you probably should have used this clause...

```
BETWEEN '2013-09-15 00:00:00' AND '2013-09-16 23:59:59'
```

... instead. Without setting the time explicitly it'll be set to '00:00:00' on both dates (as `DATETIME` values are compared here).

While it's obviously ok for the starting date, it's not so for the ending one - unless, of course, exclusion of all the records for any time of that day but midnight is actually the desired outcome.

Comment: As a sidenote, can't help wondering why do you group by `id` (and not date_time) here. )

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(consumption) 
FROM consumption_info 
WHERE date_time >= 2013-09-15 AND date_time <= 2013-09-16;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(consumption) 
FROM consumption_info 
WHERE date_time BETWEEN 2013-09-15 AND 2013-09-16;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use CAST when comparing the date function.

```
SELECT id, SUM(consumption) 
FROM consumption_info 
WHERE date_time 
    BETWEEN CAST('2013-09-15' AS DATETIME) 
    AND CAST('2013-09-16' AS DATETIME) 
GROUP BY id;
```